# Why was this flagged answer (not an answer) declined?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654791/291827) answer as not an answer, and it was declined:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

The answer does not answer the question, but adds onto the accepted answer. It does not offer an answer of its own. Without the accepted answer, this answer would make little sense (What is the "IntelliJ idea"?). But, it has the highest amount of up-votes on the question, so the community has deemed it worthy information. I don't know if this was taken into consideration when the moderation addressed the flag, or if I'm misinterpreting what can be considered an answer.

I would have thought in this situation it would be better suited as a comment to the accepted answer since it relies on the accepted answer's information. I would like to know the rationale behind keeping it as an answer, and if the amount of up-votes in an answer has any weight in the decision making process, as long as it makes a positive contribution.

Comment: IMO you needed to explain the situation/reason in the *other* section while flagging instead of just flagging as *not an answer*.

Comment: The question itself is off-topic for [so] there.

Comment: Good point @hims056. This answer walked the line a little too thin for me to assume a moderator would easily make the distinction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is useful information to the OP, which pertains directly to the question asked.  Granted, it probably would have been a better fit on the accepted answer.

If you want an answer moved in such a manner, you have to explain that with a custom flag.  Don't make the mods guess at what you're trying to do, especially on an answer that has a score of 17.  Yes, the score does matter.  So does the fact that the question is three years old, and moving the answer probably doesn't matter all that much, or we'd already moved it by now.